# Where does Ant set C compiler flags for JNI?

Tags: android, xml, ant, configuration

I'm working with Ant from the command line with Android. Ant has targets like `debug` and `release`. Searching `<sdk>/tools/ant/build.xml` is *not* showing any uses of `DEBUG`, `NDK_DEBUG` and `NDEBUG`.

Where does Ant set the prerpocessor macros when building the native components?